# com.mongodb.CommandFailureException On deleting from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have created a MongoDB database at https://mlab.com/ and now I am trying to delete a document from that MongoDB database, but I am getting `com.mongodb.CommandFailureException` Exception. Please help.

**Code:**

```
class Deletion extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URI url = new URI("mongodb://hafiz:hafizabc@ds011902.mlab.com:11902/location_notification");
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(url.getHost(),url.getPort()));
            DB db = mongo.getDB("location_notification");
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("tasks");
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.append("name", "Testing Fused");
            collection.remove(query);
            Log.e("Successfully DONE", "MongoDB", new Exception());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR","MongoDB", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
05-16 16:03:00.868 23166-23185/com.example.abc.mongo2 E/ERROR: MongoDB
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "ds011902.mlab.com:11902" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "not authorized on location_notification to execute command { delete: \"tasks\", ordered: true, deletes: [ { q: { name: \"Testing Fused\" }, limit: 0 } ] }" , "code" : 13}
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:140)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.receiveWriteCommandMessage(DBCollectionImpl.java:535)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.access$300(DBCollectionImpl.java:48)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$2.execute(DBCollectionImpl.java:474)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$2.execute(DBCollectionImpl.java:461)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:187)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:208)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:461)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.removeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:446)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.remove(DBCollectionImpl.java:223)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.remove(DBCollectionImpl.java:203)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.remove(DBCollection.java:300)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.remove(DBCollection.java:327)
at com.example.abc.mongo2.Deletion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
at com.example.abc.mongo2.Deletion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Comment: can you check if user hafiz is set to read-only in MLab database?

Comment: `read-only = false` in mlab for `hafiz` user. @Astro